# KVC array: getters vs indexed accessors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I'm confused by this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB

Supposing

```
@interface Office : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *employees;
}
```

1. What is the benefit of implementing the collection accessors?
2. How is `[anOffice countOfEmployees]` better than `[[anOffice employees] count]`?
3. Do bindings depend on the collection accessors or can I forego them completely? 
   They seem redundant to me since I'm using a true array object. I can understand how they would be needed if employees **wasn't** an `NSMutableArray` and didn't implement something like a count method itself.
4. I'm also absolutely stumped by why would would use `mutableArrayValueForKey:@"employees"` for fetching the employees property instead for simply `valueForKey:@"employees"`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* forego the collection accessors; they aren't required. But they make things a lot easier.

One reason to have them, including `countOfEmployees`, is efficiency: The `employees` method may return a copy of the array object (particularly since the Office's copy is mutable, so the Office would not want other objects mutating the array out from under it), but if you only need to know the count or to access one object at a specific index, you don't need a copy.

The other reason is when the sender wants to mutate the property.

- `valueForKey:` will call `employees`, which will ordinarily return an immutable copy.
- Returning a mutable copy would not help, since mutating that array would be mutating the copy, not the original through the property.
- Returning the original array will not enable the sender to cause KVO notifications for its changes, so nothing observing the property will know about those changes. This means the values shown in your UI will go stale (not be updated).

`mutableArrayValueForKey:` returns a fake array that sends mutation messages (or, if nothing else, `employees` and `setEmployees:` messages) back to the original object. Accessor messages do cause KVO notifications, so anything observing the property will follow along with these changes, so your UI keeps up to date.

Of course, you could just send the accessor messages yourself. `mutableArrayValueForKey:` is mainly for if you want to make changes to a property that isn't known at compile time; NSArrayController is, presumably, one user of this method. You aren't likely to need to use `mutableArrayValueForKey:` in a regular application, and sending accessor messages yourself is, in my opinion, easier to read.

All of this goes for the Office as well, when it mutates its own array. It *could* just talk to its array object directly, but that wouldn't cause KVO notifications, so nothing else would know the value of the property had changed. You could post the KVO notifications yourself around each change, but that's a hassle and easy to forget. Collection accessors and `mutableArrayValueForKey:` are two solutions to these problems: Each access is a single line of code that will cause KVO notifications.

Comment: How come [[anOffice employees] insertObject:...] isn't KVC? Presumably, objects observing the employees array should receive a notification when that's called. Second, why do you recommend the employees getter return an immutable copy? Thanks Peter.

Comment: @Alexandre: I don't know why you'd presume that. It's not correct. Mutating an array does not create any KVO notifications — the array doesn't know who's observing it and doesn't care. Change notifications are issued by the controller responsible for the array, and they won't happen if you go behind the controller's back and mutate the array directly.

Comment: The getter should not return the original array, because then the caller could mutate the array behind the controller's back, which will cause problems. If you return a mutable copy, the caller can mutate that array, so `[[anOffice employees] insertObject:…]` will not crash, but it will also not mutate the office's employees, because it mutates the copy. Code that doesn't do what it appears to do is bad. Returning an immutable copy ensures that the caller cannot mutate the original array nor mistakenly believe that it is doing so.

Comment: @Chuck: Are you assuming the Office object is the array's controller? I should have clarified that an NSArrayController is bound to the Office's employees property. In this case, who is NSArrayController observing: the Office object or the employees array? Seems like it should observe the employees array directly, that way it would be able to intercept methods like addObject, etc.
@Peter: Sorry to repeat myself - Are you assuming the Office object is the array's controller? I should have clarified that an NSArrayController is bound to the Office's employees property.

Comment: Alexandre: I had been, yes. It doesn't matter, though; regardless of whether the Office is model or controller, the array controller (NSArrayController) observes that property of the Office. It does not observe the array directly—that's impossible, as KVO notifications are always described in terms of a property of some object. See the KVO protocol, particularly the observer side of it: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keys_used_by_the_change_dictionary